# c# result in mysql = System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, mysql

in table **"skupina"** we have values **"pc1,pc2,pc3,..."**. But in this code I have result in mysql `System.Collections.Generic.List`, but should be **"pc1,pc2,pc3,...."**. Where is my mistake?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=10.7.18.35;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;"))
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT namepc FROM skupina where nazovskup= 'mojask' ", cnn); 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "skupina");

        List<string> skName = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["skupina"].Rows)
        {
            skName.Add(row["namepc"].ToString());

            string constring = "Server=10.7.18.35;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;";
            var Query = "INSERT INTO OitDB.skup(uzivatel)VALUES('" + skName + "')";
            MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDatabase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Správa odoslaná!");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

[here is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t9CA.jpg)

Comment: It's not going to work like that...You'll need to pull the values out of the list to do the insert.

Comment: You're already going through each row and getting the value out of `row["namepc"]`, why are you adding it to a list at all?  You don't do anything with the list that I can see (aside from using it improperly in your `INSERT` statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implicitly calling `ToString()` on a `List<T>`. That doesn't do what you expect it to, because `List<T>` doesn't override `ToString()`. You can use

```
// Note: the ToArray() call is only required if you're targeting .NET 3.5, which
// is massively out of date, and really shouldn't be used IMO.  
string.Join(", ", skName.ToArray())
```

to get a comma-separated result... but you really shouldn't do it where you're currently doing it. Instead, you should use parameterized SQL, e.g.

```
var query = "INSERT INTO OitDB.skup (uzivatel) VALUES (@name)";
...
cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value
    = string.Join(", ", skName.ToArray());
```

Always, always use parameterized SQL for values. You should *only* ever build SQL dynamically for non-value parts - and in that case you need to be really, really careful.

I would also suggest using `using` directives for your command and data reader... and currently you've got two different connections open, which seems unnecessary...

Comment: It didn´t work. `cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@n", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = string.Join(", ", skName));` error in skName

Comment: @Martin: Well what *exactly* is the error? Note that I had a typo - an extra `)` - but you should have been able to spot and fix that for yourself.

Comment: @Martin: Well then either you're putting this at the wrong place, or the code you're using isn't the code you've provided in the question, where `skName` is present. And the compiler should be giving you an actual error message... just "red error line" isn't the exact error.

Comment: where is true place for putting?

Comment: Well it should be just after you've created the command. It's important that you understand the answer you're trying to use before you use it - otherwise you'll end up with code you can't possibly maintain.

Comment: Just there - after the line creating `cmdDatabase`. That's assuming you still have a variable called `skName`, as per your question: `List<string> skName = new List<string>();`. My guess is that you've changed your actual code since, but it's hard to tell...

Comment: in my question is image "here is error" there you can look error

Comment: @Martin: So again, please state the *exact* error message... and ideally upload a non-lossy image so we can compare the names properly. Or just copy and paste the name from where you're declaring it to the `string.Join` call. (Also, which version of the .NET framework are you using? That might be relevant - but we should know when you finally tell us what the error message is.)

Comment: I use framework 3,5 because company need it. On image can you see red line "erron" and when I want to build the project VS ask me There were build errors. Wolud you like to continue and run the last successful build?

Comment: @Martin: Ah. If you'd mentioned that you were using a framework which was 5 years out of date, I could have found the problem easily. Or if you'd quoted the error message, which is in the error list. Always, always quote the full error message - the one that's in the list of compile-time errors. I've edited my answer now.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, when you move to .NET 4.0, you can remove the `ToArray()` call. But you should really familiarize yourself with the error list *now*, so that next time you report an error to someone, you can actually report what the error is, not just that there's a red line.

Comment: When I copy code to Win Form .NET 4.0 I have error: The name "InitializeComponent" does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Martin: Well that sounds like an entirely different problem which shouldn't be in this question. I've already shown you how to make this code work with .NET 3.5 - although you should be looking to update (ideally to the latest released framework, not just 4.0) anyway. That's a separate matter though.

Comment: But in .NET 3.5 didn´t work with this code so I change to .NET 4.0 but there is problem with InitializeComponent

Comment: @Martin: As I said before, I edited the answer to show you how to use `string.Join` with a `List<string>` in .NET 3.5. Please don't try to change multiple things at a time. If this question is about .NET 3.5, don't bring 4.0 into it (but ideally state the version in the question). If you want to ask about converting a project to 4.0, do that on a new question.

Comment: OK sorry and thank you to your answer. But now, I have other problem. (.NET 3.5) Table "skupina" has 3 rows (pc1,pc2,pc3) ... insert to uzivatel look like this (row1=pc1,row2=pc1,pc2,row3=pc1,pc2,pc3) but I need only row1=pc1, row2=pc2, row3=pc3

Comment: @Martin: "But now, I have other problem" - again, that should be a new question. **Please** understand that Stack Overflow is designed for one question per problem. That's how it's useful to future visitors.

Comment: OK. I understand. Thank you for all in this question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are left with flattening your List to a string like:

```
 // Convert the ArrayList to a string
    string separator = "|"; // Any string that doesn't collide with content
    string arrayListAsString = String.Join(separator, skName.ToArray());
```

Then save the string in the database. When reading the string from the database you'll probably want to convert it back to an ArrayList:

```
// Convert the string back to an List
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.AddRange(arrayListAsString.Split(new string[]{separator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: No, not an `ArrayList`. Why would the OP want to use a non-generic collection? It's not 2004 :)